# Google Script SetFormula escaping quotes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I cannot figure out the right combination of single and double quotes and \ to get this setFormula to work right.

```
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setFormula('=query(arrayformula(Master!A:K), "SELECT B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K where A = '"& 'Select Your Event'!A3 &"' Order By I, J",1)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\'` instead of `'` on QUERY function literals inside the SQL argument

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setFormula('=query(arrayformula(Master!A:K), "SELECT B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K where A = \'"& \'Select Your Event\'!A3 &"\' Order By I, J",1)')`

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize I has to escape the double quotes and the single quotes.